# Can not run a command at startup in ubuntu14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, startup, programming, execute-command

I am trying to run command with start up of computer, for that I add the command in `cd /etc && sudo gedit rc.local` But still when I restart the computer it's not running automatically. I have attached the screen shot. Please can anyone help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a wrong place to run second and third commands in `rc.local`, because they should be run later when GUI is loaded and you log in into the system.

The easiest way is to add these commands to "Startup Applications" that can be found in Dash.

[image]